# How do I pick the color in hexadecimal form or RGB form instead of using the colors given to me in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, rgb, uicolor

I am trying to change the background color of    TopScoreContainer    to a lighter shade of green. I do not want to use    greenColor()    . Here is the line of code:

```
self.TopScoreContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Is it possible to substitute in a hexadecimal number or RGB value instead of    greenColor()    ? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
    let myCustomColorHSBa = UIColor(hue: 120/360, saturation: 0.25 , brightness: 1.0 , alpha: 1)
    let myCustomColorRGBa = UIColor(red: 191/255, green: 1, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1)
```

using it as an extension read-only computed var:

> Read-Only Computed Properties
>
> A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a
>   read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always
>   returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be
>   set to a different value.
>
> NOTE
>
> You must declare computed properties—including read-only computed
>   properties—as variable properties with the var keyword, because their
>   value is not fixed. The let keyword is only used for constant
>   properties, to indicate that their values cannot be changed once they
>   are set as part of instance initialization.
>
> You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by
>   removing the get keyword and its braces:

```
extension UIColor {
    var lightGreen: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 191/255, green: 1, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
let lightGreen = UIColor().lightGreen
```

or you can also create your own htmlColor input as follow:

update: **Xcode 7.2 • Swift 2.1.1**

```
extension String {
    subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> String {
        return range.startIndex < 0 || range.endIndex > characters.count ? "Out of Range" : substringWithRange(Range(start: startIndex.advancedBy(range.startIndex),end: startIndex.advancedBy(range.endIndex)))
    }
    var hexaCGFloat: CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(strtoul(self, nil, 16))
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(htmlColor: String, alpha: Double) {
        self.init(red: htmlColor[1...2].hexaCGFloat / 255.0, green: htmlColor[3...4].hexaCGFloat / 255.0, blue: htmlColor[5...6].hexaCGFloat / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(alpha)  )
    }
    convenience init(r: Int, g:Int , b:Int , a: Int) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255, green: CGFloat(g)/255, blue: CGFloat(b)/255, alpha: CGFloat(a)/255)
    }
}
let myColor = UIColor(r: 255 , g: 0, b: 0, a: 255)
let myHtmlWebColor = UIColor(htmlColor: "#bfffbf", alpha: 1.0)
```