# How do you make a label a specific color in Sprite Kit with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How Do you set a SKLabel node to have a specific color(such as hex color code or RGB color) not just a SKColor in Xcode 6 using the gaming technology Sprite Kit and the language Swift?

I know how to do this

```
label.fontcolor = UIColor.bluecolor()
```

but I want a specific color of blue to match my application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27698546/2303865

Answer (score 3):

You can use RGB values like this:

```
var color = SKColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

SKColor is a macro that expands to UIColor on iOS or NSColor on OSX so you can use the docs for [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:) and [NSColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use hex colors.

```
self.label.fontcolor = UIColor(hex: 0xFFFFE5)
```

But be aware that it's not providing alpha mask and you probably will need to make color extension.

Make a new file and put extension in. For example:

```
extension UIColor {
convenience init(hex: Int, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    let red = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
    let green = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
    let blue = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF)) / 255.0
    self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
```

}
}