# Using Extension for Converting Hex to UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, hex, uicolor

I find using hex codes file defining colours much easier than rgba, so I researched about how to use a converter from hex code to UIColor. I first created a new file called `UIColorUtility` and added:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    public convenience init?(hexString: String) {
        let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

        if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {
            let start = hexString.startIndex.advancedBy(1)
            let hexColor = hexString.substringFromIndex(start)

            if hexColor.characters.count == 8 {
                let scanner = NSScanner(string: hexColor)
                var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

                if scanner.scanHexLongLong(&hexNumber) {
                    r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                    g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                    b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                    a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255

                    self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Then in my viewController, I tried to change this bit

`.SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.153, blue: 0.106, alpha: 1.0)),`

into this bid:

`.SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(hexString: "#929292"))!,`

*It first forced me to unwrap it, and then started giving me error..*

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

What am I doing wrong? Also, just out of curiosity, how can I set the alpha too after applying hexString approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696862/what-is-the-best-shortest-way-to-convert-a-uicolor-to-hex-web-color-in-swift/28697136?s=1|0.1545#28697136

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698533/how-do-i-pick-the-color-in-hexadecimal-form-or-rgb-form-instead-of-using-the-col/27698546?s=1|0.5785#27698546

Comment: @Leo, I used [this approach](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uicolor/how-to-convert-a-hex-color-to-a-uicolor), but why mine isn't working?

Comment: I had to update the code to work with Swift 2. Try with the updated code

Comment: BTW your problem with that code was the parameter input length that needs to be 8 characters and you were passing only 6

Comment: .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(hexString: "#929292"))!

You try use RGB Value (6 symbols) but u code for correct work want 8 (RGBA color). set hex value as .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(hexString: "#929292FF"))!