# Button Text - UIColor from Hex? SWIFT

Tags: swift, text, uibutton, hex, uicolor

Here's a line to change my button text to green

```
self.button.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

That gives me just your standard green color.  Is there a way to use a hex number?  I've got a hex number for the pale shade of green I need just not at my computer at the moment sorry.

*Also this color change is happening after I click the button, just didn't bother posting that part of the code.  I do know I can select any color it initially displays in my storyboard section.

Any guidance or help greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27698546/2303865

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be the code:

```
UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 204/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0) /* #ffcc00 */
```

also a very useful tool/ website for converting the colors into useful Swift code:

https://www.ralfebert.de/snippets/ios/swift-uicolor-picker/

## Edit:

Example:

```
self.button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.28, blue:0.28, alpha:1.0), forState: .Normal)
```

or if you want a cleaner solution:

```
var myColor = UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.28, blue:0.28, alpha:1.0)
self.button.setTitleColor(myColor, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Cool website!  Maybe I was searching the wrong thing before.  Looks like you can use either RGB or HEX it's just a different approach?  I found one thing that talked about using an extension to create custom colours then just name it whatever and replace "greenColor" with your custom name, I had my heart set on hex for some reason. I think that limited my search results.

Comment: Yes there are a lot of tools outside, you can either use hex or rgb. There is the approach to handle it over an extension as you mentioned and another possibilty would be to store it in a variable and reuse it. Thats completly up to you:)

Comment: Saving my up vote for when I can try them both out but I definitely will!

Comment: Your first suggestion worked best for me.  I was able to just make a color and grab the RGB values.  Just made the most sense to me.  Thank you Anokrize!

Comment: I do have a question, the edited way, using 0.96 vs 221/255...what is happening with those numbers?  I played around with them a bit but couldn't get the results I wanted hence the reason using 221/255 over 0.96.  I was having trouble getting a light color.  I tried lowering the alpha but then I could see my shadow behind text which I didn't want.

Comment: Well I got it using the 221/255 way but of course my numbers were different.  I was just aiming for a very light pale shade of green.  Using something like 0.96 or 0.28 I just kept getting very bold colors.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code and a screenshot maybe?

Comment: I think I figured out how changing the numbers work.  They're like a percentage for each.  Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 10):

You add a `UIColor` extension in your project to do so:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(rgb: UInt) {
        self.init(rgb: rgb, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    convenience init(rgb: UInt, alpha: CGFloat) {
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(alpha)
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
let brown = UIColor(rgb: 0xBE5300)  // BE5300 is the hex value
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have hex components {dd, fe, a8}. You can construct a `UIColor` from them by using initializer that takes individual components, like this:

```
color = UIColor(
    red: Float(0xDD) / 255.0
, green: Float(0xFE) / 255.0
,  blue: Float(0xA8) / 255.0
, alpha: Float(1)
)
```

Comment: Ok maybe I got something wrong, the hex I got was all letters.  It's like DDFGD something. :( lol

Comment: @Brad That's OK, hex is a mixture of numbers and letters, so all letters is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok I'll try it tonight as soon as I can.  And do I need that "return" or can I stuff the red green blue float stuff into my orginal line of code.  Sorry I'm a newborn when it comes to programming just thought I'd try it out.

Comment: @Brad Possibly of interest (in addition to the above) for you: see _Bitwise Left and Right Shift Operators_ section in [Language Guide - Advanced Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) for an enlightening example of hex. and RBG triplets.

Comment: Should be CGFloat not Foat

Comment: Much easier to just do 0xDD / 0xFF

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was hoping for: here use this color and pick it with the eye dropper tool. Lol. I think I may be in over my head. :P